# Why does (function($) { $.widget()})(jQuery) fail but $(function(){$widget()}); does not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to upgrade an application from jQuery 1.12.4 to 3.1.1 I have several of scripts that are failing in a specific way, but I don't understand the reason. Here is what I am seeing.

code that looks like this:

```
(function( $ ) {
$.widget("ui.voicerecorder", 
{  
...
});

})( jQuery );
```

throws the error: Object doesn't support property or method 'widget'

However, if I change this to:

```
$(function() {
$.widget("ui.voicerecorder", 
{  
...
});

});
```

the error goes away, but later in jQuery I get that same error again: Object doesn't support property or method 'widget'. I'm not real sure where to look, or why changing the definition of the widget makes a difference.

The error in jQuery 3.1.1 occurs at line 3855.

**Edit:**
Here is the order of the script tags in the header:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="rui/scripts/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.js?v=5.15b"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="rui/scripts/jquery/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js?v=5.15b"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="rui/scripts/require-2.3.2.js?v=5.15b"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="rui/scripts/jquery/ui/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js?v=5.15b"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="rui/scripts/jquery/jquery.misc.js?v=5.15b"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="rui/scripts/jquery/ui/jquery.menuopts.js?v=5.15b"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="rui/scripts/jquery/ui/jquery.inbox.js?v=5.15b"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="rui/scripts/jquery/ui/jquery.themechanger.js?v=5.15b"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="rui/scripts/jquery/ui/jquery.voicerecorder.js?v=5.15b"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="rui/scripts/jquery/ui/jquery.keypad.js?v=5.15b"></script>
```

The pieces that cause this error are the widget pieces: jquery.menuopts.js, inbox, themechanger, voicerecorder, keypad. As you can see they are all after jquery_ui which loads the widget code. If I change back to jquery 1.12, and jquery-ui 1.8, everything loads properly with the first syntax. Could this be a timing issue? I am using IE 11.0.

Comment: The first one runs immediately when the page is loaded  while the latter will wait until the page is ready and _then_ run. The two pieces of code are really rather different in what they do. In either case, I believe you don't import JS file that adds `.widget` to jQuery.

Comment: You should check out the [jQuery Migrate Plugin](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#jquery-migrate-plugin); it throws lots of specific errors that are helpful when upgrading jQuery versions.

Comment: I am using the Migrate Plugin, it is just throwing a few deprecation warnings.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example the widget has presumably not yet loaded. The code runs immediately in an immediately-executed function.

However in the second example you use a document ready handler, so is running at a later time.

```
$(function() {//...
```